# How to run database from xampp vm to apache server?

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am developing a API in xampp virtual machine, with a Database created in xampp vm also, but some of the data I receive and that I want to store in my database, comes through a webhook I set on my Apache server. How can I store the webhook information on my database created through my xampp virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

So, since it is still in production, I used a ngrok tunnel to redirect the webhook there and do the logic in my xampp vm. 
Hope it my help someone on the future!